# Updating a list of tuples if a value appears in a different set of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Lets say i have a list of tuples

```
tl = [("x","y"), ("y","z"), ("y","a")]
```

and for every tuple in the list I want to replace the occurrence of the first item in the tuple in the rest of the tuples except the tuple I'm currently working with so it would be something like this.

**First iteration**:  This is the first tuple in the list: `("x","y")`

Now I want to find if `"x"` appears in any of the other tuples except the tuple I'm currently working with. Since there aren't any other `"x"`'s the list will stay the same.

After:

```
tl = [("x","y"), ("y","z"), ("y","a")]
```

**Second iteration**: This is the second tuple in the list: `("y","z")`

I want to find if `"y"` appears in any of the other tuples except the tuple I'm currently working with. In this case there is another `"y"` in the third tuple `("y","a")` so we have to replace it with `"z"`.

After: The third tuple was changed from `("y","a")` to `("z","a")`

```
tl = [("x","z"), ("y","z"), ("z","a")]
```

**Third iteration**: This is the third tuple in the list `("z","a")`.

I want to find if `"z"` appears in any of the other tuples except the one I'm currently working with and replace `"z"` with `"a"`. In this case `"z"` appears in the first and second tuple.

After: The first tuple changed from `("x","z")` to `("x","a")`. The second tuple changed from `("y","z")` to `("y","a")`.

```
tl = [("x","a"), ("y","a"), ("z","a")]
```

Since we already iterated all the items in the list we can stop and `[("x","a"), ("y","a"), ("z","a")]` is the result.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? and will it be easier to achieve it if I have a  dictionary instead?

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing your requirement and applying it to your examples. In general, if you want to replace values in a tuple, you're not looking for a tuple at all, but a list.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Can you try to elaborate on exactly what you need to do? Why is the first iteration `("x", "y")`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so on the first iteration I'm looking for all the occurrences of the value "x" in the rest of the tuples and if I find the value "x" it will be replaces with the value "y" and so on for the rest of the tuples.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you tell us *exactly* which `"x"`s you find and which `"y"`s you actually put in for the case of the first iteration?

Comment: @quamrana I updated the question.

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear, your first code snippet has nothing to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: It looks like the first list shown is actually the list you want to _get to_ not _start with_

Comment: "This is the first tuple in the list :("x","y")" no? `tl = [("x","a"),("y","a"),("z","a")]`... the first one is `("x","a")`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I place the wrong list at the beginning . I update the question

Comment: Maybe you could start by replacing all the tuples with lists, do the processing and replace the lists with tuples as a final step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *O(n^2)*, which is the most efficient way until proven otherwise ;)

```
tl = [("x","y"), ("y","z"), ("y","a")]

for i, (find, replace) in enumerate(tl):
    for j, t in enumerate(tl):
        if j != i:  # Skip self
            tl[j] = tuple(replace if x == find else x for x in t)

print(tl)  # -> [('x', 'a'), ('y', 'a'), ('z', 'a')]
```

I don't know how you would use a dict for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary at the beginning with references to items in output list:

```py
tl = [("x", "y"), ("y", "z"), ("y", "a")]

out, d = [], {}
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(tl):
    l = [a, b]
    out.append(l)
    d.setdefault(a, []).append((i, l))
    if a != b:
        d.setdefault(b, []).append((i, l))

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(out):
    for idx, l in d.get(a, []):
        if idx != i:
            if l[0] == a:
                l[0] = b
            if l[1] == a:
                l[1] = b
            d[a].remove((idx, l))
            d[b].append((idx, l))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[['x', 'z'], ['y', 'a'], ['z', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, therefore I think you're better off using a dictionary.

Here is my solution

```
tl = [("x","y"), ("y", "z"), ("y","a")]

def my_function(tl):
    ll = [list(tup) for tup in tl]
    llen = len(ll)
    for i in range(llen):
        for j in range(llen):
            if j==i:
                continue
            if ll[i][0] == ll[j][0]:
                ll[j][0] = ll[i][1]

            if ll[i][0] == ll[j][1]:
                ll[j][1] = ll[i][1]

    res = [tuple(l) for l in ll]
    return res

tl = my_function(tl)
print(tl) # -> [('x', 'a'), ('y', 'a'), ('z', 'a')]
```

"i" will serve as the current list that is referenced and "j" is the list that is being changed if need be. The inner loop skips over the list being referenced.

Let me know if you have any questions or if you find any problems with the code.

Comment: @wjandrea can you please elaborate? Am I using a dict in a way that it isn't supposed to be used?

Comment: Consider `ld = [["x","y"], ["y", "z"], ["y","a"]]`. You woudn't need to change the function at all, and it's more intuitive.

Comment: And if you're using this function in other situations, `list(range(len(ld)))` might not be equal to `sorted(ld.keys())`, which would cause `KeyError`s.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Hopefully this edit is better.